# How to print a PDF to a new PDF from Acrobat in OSX

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

I have a document that I want to shrink by putting four pages on each sheet.

Doing this is easy enough in Acrobat when you are printing the file, but I want to save the resulting output as a PDF so I can view it on my computer in the new layout. If I try to select PDF as the printer, Acrobat tells me that it can't print to PDF.

Is there any way to do this? I'm running Acrobat Pro DC on OSX.

Comment: If you can't find a way to save it to a new PDF in Acrobat, load one of the free PDF print drivers.  They show up as a printer that you select, only their output is a PDF.  There is often one bundled with Linux.  If you're using Windows and it doesn't come with one, they're readily available online.

Comment: I'm on neither Linux nor Windows. What's available for OSX?

Comment: Asking for product recommendations is off-topic.  I don't use a Mac, but I thought they were pretty good about supporting PDF and bundling PDF tools.  If not, I just Googled "osx pdf print driver" and got a whole page of reviews and recommendations.  Not being a Mac user, I can't really add anything of value to that.